# How to send post to WordPress with REST API

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have a Script that can send post to WordPress web site using REST API and now i need to send post with some more features first make post that have post type and second is call and set value to some custom fields

here is my python code :

```
auth = 'Basic ' + str(base64.b64encode(b'jason:WdOb zgW5 Oq5I LhT3 9Gkw tiJg'), 'utf-8')
                headers = {'Authorization': auth}
                body = {'title': pointer , 'content': myresult_pointer[0] ,'categories':categories_id,'status':"publish",'comment_status':"open"}
                r = requests.post('http://aaa.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', headers=headers, data=body)
```

and the url of the post type (bold part):

http://aaa.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?**post_type=movies**

another thing is when i run the code it return this :

`{'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.2.22', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'x-robots-tag': 'noindex', 'link': '<http://aaa.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages', 'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type', 'content-length': '113', 'date': 'Fri, 25 Oct 2019 20:04:58 GMT', 'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'connection': 'close'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to create a post with custom post type, WordPress has it's own REST API to create a post. Refer [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post).

Else if you have certain specific requirements that the default API does not support then you need to create a new custom endpoint. You can find help from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/). There you write your logic to authenticate your API requests, creating post with POST data, saving extra field values or meta.

Comment: yes i just need to create but it dose not work , can you help me to do this ????

Comment: Sure. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: actually my web site was OK with this code since i change the Theme of the site and the default post changed to Movies i cant send any post in to the web site with this code . 
in the new theme the posts should be sent in to this Dir **r = requests.post('http://aaa.com/wp-json/wp/v2/movies'**

, if you have any social media or Email please give me to contact with you and share more info about my code : **mohamad76wp@gmail.com**

Comment: Sorry i cant access to FB please send massage  to whatsapp or EMail, +988213637895

Comment: I am not able to find you on whatsapp

Comment: sorry my bad , +989213637895